# What is a good way to rename multiple parameters that share the same purpose?

Tags: c#, parameters, naming-conventions, naming

What is the common way of naming parameters in a method like the following?

```
void MyMethod(int[] series1, int[] series2) { ... }
```

The two arrays there have the same purpose, maybe the method takes two arrays of names, or two series, or something similar. What is a common way to name such parameters? Would you use `parameter1, parameter2, ...` or `firstParameter, secondParameter, ...` or something else?

I would appreciate if you could give me an example of such a method in the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: If they have the same purpose, why have 2 arrays instead of one? They probably do not have the same purpose, meaning they should each be named according to their actual purpose.

Comment: @Oded Let's say they are two series that will be compared.

Comment: From string.Format: arg0, arg1, arg2.   From Comparer.Compare: x, y

Comment: Looks like you got it then. The method name would be `Compare`, giving all the needed semantics.

Comment: @David - It is actually `params object[] args`.

Comment: @Oded - In .Net 4.0 at least, it has a couple of overloads for the simple cases.

Comment: If you have two series to compare, calling the parameters `series1` and `series2` is fine, so long as the method name is `Compare`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few examples:

- [Tuple.Create<T1, T2> Method (T1, T2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx)

  ```
  public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)
  ```
- [String.Compare Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx)

  ```
  public static int Compare(string strA, string strB)
  ```
- [String.Equality Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx)

  ```
  public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
  ```
- [Object.ReferenceEquals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)

  ```
  public static bool ReferenceEquals(Object objA, Object objB)
  ```
- [XNode.DeepEquals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx)

  ```
  public static bool DeepEquals(XNode n1, XNode n2)
  ```
- [Expression.Equal Method (Expression, Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749.aspx)

  ```
  public static BinaryExpression Equal(Expression left, Expression right)
  ```
- [TimeSpan.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare.aspx)

  ```
  public static int Compare(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2)
  ```
- [String.Concat Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx)

  ```
  public static string Concat(string str0, string str1)
  ```

I don't think there's a convention that is consistently used throughout the .NET framwork.
The method names make it quite clear what the parameters mean though.

Comment: For binary operations I usually use `left` and `right`.

Comment: awesome memory to have fetched this list in few mins! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it is common.

However, if the method reflects a documented algorithm, then using names that match that algorithm is better.